# IE iframe problem with getElementById

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, getelementbyid

i have an iframe which contains a page with a div that i use to load some graphs. Sadly IE wont find the div with the function document.getElementById, but firefox will do without problem. Any hint whats going on? Thanks

```
<iframe id="ganttFrame" src="data.html">
```

data.html:

```
<div class="gantt" id="GanttChartDIV"></div>
<script>    
  var g = new JSGantt.GanttChart('g',document.getElementById('GanttChartDIV'), 'day');
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure you are trying to access the frame after the iframe is loaded? - also, IE has historically had a bug with getElementById() if there is an element higher up in the DOM with the `name` attribute with the same value... any chance you have an element with the same name before the iframe?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to access the div inside the iframe. Checked twice, the name is unique. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to get the element like this since it is actually part of a separate window.

```
document.getElementById('ganttFrame').document.getElementById('GanttChartDIV')
//                       ^^^get the iframe's document... the the ^^^^
```

or you could use (if your iframe has a `name` attribute set to `ganttFrame`):

```
window.frames['ganttFrame'].document.getElementById('GanttChartDIV')
```

In theory, each iframe *could* contain exact duplicate ID's because it is a separate document, thus to navigate to it properly, you'll need to get the iframe, then in that "window" get the child div.